# Where is the XMLTransformProvider component in the Delphi XE2 palette?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

It looks like this is the tool I need to ingest XML and connect with a TClientDataset.  I have seen it mentioned in several posts and in documentation but I cannot find it in the XE2 component list - anywhere!  Where is it supposed to be?  Is it in an optional package that is perhaps not installed?

I thought it might be due to the fact that I am dually deploying to Win and OSX, but starting a fresh Windows-only project doesn't make it magically appear.  I feel foolish even asking but just can't find the thing.

TIA

Comment: Maybe you need higher edition, like enterprise version?

Comment: It's at least in version Professional. Anyway, one fast way how to find component on palette is to press `CTRL + ALT + P` when you have your form designer displayed and type what you are looking for.

Comment: It's in XE2 Professional (and all the way back at least to D2007), on the `Data Access` tab of the palette. It's a VCL-related component, I believe, and is only available in VCL applications (which would explain why it's not showing up for you - are you working on a FM app instead?).

Comment: Ken - yes, you are right.  It's that I was doing an FM app.  ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Enterprise Edition to have that

[Delphi XE2 Feature Matrix](http://www.embarcadero.com/images/dm/products/delphi_xe2_feature_matrix.pdf)

Comment: The Enterprise eval is what I've got.  Is it only available for VCL Forms and not Firemonkey apps?

Comment: It is in the VCL structure.  So you cannot directly use it in Firemonkey apps.  However, if you use datasnap, you can use it in the datasnap server, which you can create server methods using its functionality.  Those server method can be call by Firemonkey client.

Comment: Hmm...that might do the trick.  Thanks!  I shall investigate!!

Answer (score 3):

The [`TXMLTransformProvider`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/Xmlxform.TXMLTransformProvider) component is in the data access tab. and is included in the Enterprise version.

[image]